# Why does these stray cats keep coming to my house

Tags: cats

So recently these stray cats started coming to my house, and even tho I'm a dog person, I pet them and they started adjusting to me. But now they come to my house everyday at morning and night, everytime I leave, they come to my house and look at me like they want me to come. So I don't understand why these cats come to my house, like I am fine with it, but what other special feature does it include to attract cats to my house. I tried researching this on Google but it's just give me a boring reason, I want a good easy answer that is not basic or generic.

Answer (score 2):

Cats are beggars that like to snack all day long. They will visit every house that MIGHT have food for them. If you show them any attention, they will check frequently to see if you have anything for them.

As an example, my cat has her "daily rounds" and is happy to visit anyone she thinks will feed her. She will even go inside their homes. If she sees one of her 'regulars' pull into their driveway, she's waiting at their door by the time they get out of their car. My previous cat of 20 years did this, too. At all times my cat has food and water available, she hangs out on my deck most of the day, and she sleeps and cuddles with me at night, so there is no confusion which is her actual home and her primary human. And since my old dog has passed away I'm spotting other neighborhood cats visiting my property at night on THEIR rounds (which I don't encourage, but I'm willing to let them check/hunt for small rodents at night).

So I doubt the local cats' attraction to you is any more mysterious than convenience and opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

Look at you as their owner? Ahahaha... In case you missed it: **You** and your house are under new management now.

While animals like dogs stay with their owners, because they want to form a pack with an actual hierarchy, cats are a *bit* different. They stay out of convenience: shelter, scratches, food, etc. They don't feel owned nor do they necessarily see you as superior or even just equal.

Whenever they push their chin at you or some object or wall? They don't cuddle, they claim ownership. You're theirs now, subject!